# Java invoke listing files from command line

Tags: java, file, command-line

I try to invoke file listing from command line using java. it looks like that:

```
try {
p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /k dir /b /S /a-d \"C:\\Image");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())
    );
```

and then I ready line by line... and this is working.

But I want to get also filename and filesize, so I try to invoke like that:

```
try {
p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe for %F in (\"C:\\Image*\") do @echo %~zF  %F");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())
    );
```

and this return me only two lines:
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
which is not a filename and filesize;)

is this is possible to get those infomarion (filesize) by invoking cmd from java code?

Comment: Is there a reason for wanting to do it this way, rather than using the Java libraries? What you're doing will be very fragile and will only work on Windows.

Comment: And also invoking third-party programs makes your system vulnerable: imagine if `cmd.exe` was a masked infected file

Comment: Env is only windows. I need to run using command line, because in some location I need to list 5k-10-15k files. Which is a performance killer if I use just java File...
I'm not totally sure bu tlisting using shell should be a lot faster and decrease IO to disk. Basically I need to know about file three info: filename, file size and last modify date.

Comment: @user1055201 I can't see why it would decrease file I/O, but in any case I've posted an answer that explains where I think the error is, and how to do it with the more modern `Files` rather than `File`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question *as it stands* is that you're looking in `C:\Image*`, and I think you meant to look at `C:\Image\*`. Try changing the relevant bit to

```
(\"C:\\Image\\*\")
```

(You might need `*.*`, depending on whether Windows has caught up with the rest of the world recently.)

But you really shouldn't be doing it like this at all. The right way to do it is this:

```
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*")) {
    for (Path entry: stream) {
        System.out.println(entry.toString()+" has size "+Files.size(entry)
             +" and date "+Files.getLastModifiedTime(entry).toString());
    }
} catch (DirectoryIteratorException ex) {
    // do some error processing
}
```

I can't see any reason to think that a shell command will be any faster. It's doing the same disk I/O.

Comment: changed to (\"C:\\Image\\*\")
didn't help.

Comment: @user1055201 but note the double backslash before the `*`!

Comment: yes I use double "\" (in other case code not compile)

Answer (score 2):

use the `File` class to get the file size and file name:

```
public void listFilesForFolder(File folder) {
    for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getTotalSpace());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already use java File and for my locations with 10k-15k files perfromance is not good, thats why I want to check how it will work using Shell command .

Comment: you can show a user progress bar to know their progress, but doing it with shell to get the extra minute or so in compare to working only with the language is not good in my opinion(it's debatable)

Comment: I don't want to show progess. User need to get list of files as fast as possible, he couldn't wait for simple list 3-4 minutes.